# Simplify constant variables mapped to union type

Tags: typescript

I'm defining a union type with some constant variables:

```js
type Token = '+' | '-';
const TOKEN_PLUS: Token = '+';
const TOKEN_MINUS: Token = '-';
```

I feel that somehow it can be simplified.
I don't like having to repeat the '+' and '-' (could be many more).

Any ideas on how to simplify?

Comment: Seems like a good use-case for an enum - why don't you have that?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Can you expand on your use cases?  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w14YkW) would work (which is essentially an `enum` but doesn't have some of the baggage of `enum`), but it depends on what you want to do with `Token` and the corresponding constant variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of possibilities here. Usually, I will not export const representations of members of a union type, since the typechecker and auto-complete will let me use the strings as values instead, if you have a solid reason to keep things as they are I would suggest inverting the code.

```
const TOKEN_PLUS = '+';
const TOKEN_MINUS = '-';

type Token = typeof TOKEN_PLUS | typeof TOKEN_MINUS;

const test: Token = TOKEN_PLUS // okay
const test2: Token = '+' // okay
const fail: Token = '$' // error
```

Alternatively, you could consider an enum, which would combine your consts and type with just the enum, but you would not be able to use a string literal to initialize a value

```
enum Token {
  Plus = '+',
  Minus = '-'
}

const test3 = Token.Plus // okay
const test4: Token = '+' // not okay
```

Comment: Presumably, the reason for declaring the constants is so that they should be used instead of string literals. So this is actually an advantage of using an enum, not a disadvantage.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't disagree, I think it entirely depends on the use-case/preference of the developer.  From a pure TypeScript perspective - the string-literal is just as typesafe as a constant reference.